# Slow ubuntu mirrors in AWS

Tags: apt, amazon-ec2, aws, mirrors

We are currently having some very serious issues with VM's started in `eu-west-1` region in AWS.

The machines are started from cannonical AMI (`ami-77057e00`).

The repositories configured are:

- http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
- http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu

The repositories are excruciatingly slow, but still responding. So basically the machines take ages to become operational (if we wait enough (6+ hours f.e.). And this is happening for several days.

Can you please alert the mirror maintainers? or Help in any way

Comment: For now you could to change the repos with something like this:
`sudo sed -i 's;eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com;eu.archive.ubuntu.com;' /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Well the repos come from baked ami's and aside from moving to a custom ami i am not able to change them before first full boot. The issue seems to subside now but we'll keep monitoring it.

Comment: Ah that's a shame. Yes it seems better now :) Good luck!

Comment: Is this because of journaling (ext4 file system ?) - because here is encrypted hard-disk with ext4 file system and 15.04 LTS2 and with each login and done desktop work then logout again the harddisk is getting slowlier too - bleachbit is not possible, because bleachbit works only with encrypted harddisks.

Comment: Nope, it was definitely slow mirrors. FS has no impact when mounted and operational (on mount/umount it might have effect but not in operation)

Answer (score -1):

Hello Chicks and Zeridon, do you know apt-spy ?! This debian command is present in Ubuntu too.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man8/apt-spy.8.html

With apt-spy you could generate a new sources.list as to your wishes.

Comment: Making sources.list was not the problem. The problem was a slow mirror in a cloud system with no access to it while booting (by design). The question is irrelevant for quite some time already.